iPhoneのブラウザでhttpアクセスでカメラを起動する方法
カメラを使用するWebシステムを開発しています。
HTTPSのリバースプロキシが用意できず、HTTPでアクセスしています。
windowsやAndroidのChrome場合は、unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secureオプションを有効にすることで、HTTPでもカメラを起動できますが、iPhoneのChromeには同様のオプションが無いようです。
iPhoneからHTTPでアクセスしたサイトでWebカメラを有効にする方法はあるでしょうか。
あくまで開発環境ですので、「開発者オプションを有効にする」など特殊な操作があってもかまいません。
また、ブラウザの縛りはありません。

この辺の記事が参考(か検索を続けるヒント)になるかもしれませんね。HTMLだけでiPhoneなどスマホのカメラを起動できるcapture属性, Accessing the camera in iOS Safari on an iPhone, 【JavaScript】iPhoneでカメラ(videoタグ)が動かない時の設定

私の知ってる限りでは、iPhoneはセキュリティ厳しいんでHTTP環境でWebカメラを直接有効にする方法は無いと思います。
